# How to send two values trough serial communication to Arduino?

Tags: arduino

How do I send two values to two differents variables on the Arduino board trough serial communication  for example with Visual C#?

Answer (score 0):

You send a text like "A=123\n"  or "B=0\n"
and interpret the incoming text on the Arduino.

You have full control over the syntax, so make it easy:

- special character to recognize end of message : e.g.newline '\n' in C++ / c#
- special character to disinguish between value and name e.g. '='
- single character to distinguish variable names (easy switch-case construct)
- ascii conversation to allow testing with standard tools
  (e.g. Arduino SerialMonitor instead of your C# program)